# How to install google fonts on RedHat 7 for all users

Tags: linux, fonts, redhat-enterprise-linux

I see that it's possible to download Google fonts from their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/fonts). Is it also possible to install these fonts on a RedHat 7 machine? Or maybe, what is the best way to install these fonts on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 5):

I followed the approach outlined [here](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/01/01/how-to-addinstall-ubuntu-fonts-in-centosred-hat-linux/) and [here](http://sharadchhetri.com/2016/07/23/install-google-fonts-on-ubuntu-system/).

```
cd
sudo wget https://github.com/google/fonts/archive/main.zip
unzip main.zip
sudo cp -rvf fonts-main /usr/share/fonts
fc-cache -fv
```

Comment: I will try it with my RHEL 8

Comment: Thank you for this :)